# Why does moving this Togglebutton definition result in crash?

Tags: android, android-widget, adt

In my app i have a button that turns bluetooth on and off, something that i noticed is that when i move the togglebutton defintion to the top of the class and out of `onResume();` the app crashes with nullpointerexception, here is the short version of the code that crashes:

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {
        static final BluetoothAdapter myBluetooth = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        final ToggleButton tglbtn = (ToggleButton)findViewById(R.id.ToggleButton01);

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if(myBluetooth == null){
            setContentView(R.layout.notsupported);  
        }
        else{
            setContentView(R.layout.supported);
        }
    }

        @Override
        public void onResume()
        {
            super.onResume();
            tglbtn.setChecked(myBluetooth.isEnabled());
            tglbtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
                 public void onClick(View v) { .......}
            }
        }
    }
```

When i move `final ToggleButton tglbtn = (ToggleButton)findViewById(R.id.ToggleButton01);`
back into `onResume()`, the app works fine and doesn't crash, can someone explain why this happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are assigning your Views in the onCreate() right? Specifically it should be happening after the setContentView(X). The reason for this is because all views will be non-null at this point.

Comment: Ya i do set the view in onCreate, changed my example to show what i do.

Comment: You should not be finding the view outside of onCreate. Specifically the only thing you should have outside of the onCreate in your case is a button. There is no reason for it to be static.

Comment: So basically i cant refer to a resource(button, textview etc) contained in a layout until setContentView(); has been called for that particular layout?